# javascript google maps API encoding.decodePath returns invalid LatLng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used the javascript API and I'm using an encoded path that i get from "Strava" (running app).

My code looks like this:

```
var decoded_latlngs = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('c{|xHbo|OSnFrSjW~M{EnFwVz@wy@vQsq@cBoUzJ{EzObBrIcLfE~C~H{Y~C~CfOgY{EjM{EgTcLzTsSwQcGf@IoKgJSkMsb@RkRvVkRDon@SooBvBsXbGgE{@{EfE{EwLsXgEo{AcVgw@kRc|A_q@seAcLg@bBvQkCnKcGjCwQsSkM?cL{YjHrS{J~HgOwBgOjf@{Jju@cLjRcGz^oUjW{Tni@f@jRsIj\wBjf@sNbo@wG~iArDnlArIj\bGfr@bQf^~WrSnPvVfOjHnURzc@cQbQzc@nUrtAbBfYkC~M~HnZ~Mz^f^_N~MrDbBwQkWsXR{E');

console.log("decoded_latlngs:", decoded_latlngs)
```

However i get this error in the javascript console:

```
decoded_latlngs: [_.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K]0: _.K1: _.K2: _.K3: _.K4: _.K5: _.K6: _.K7: _.K8: _.K9: _.K10: _.K11: _.K12: _.K13: _.K14: _.K15: _.K16: _.K17: _.K18: _.K19: _.K20: _.K21: _.K22: _.K23: _.K24: _.K25: _.K26: _.K27: _.K28: _.K29: _.K30: _.K31: _.K32: _.K33: _.K34: _.K35: _.K36: _.K37: _.K38: _.K39: _.K40: _.K41: _.K42: _.K43: _.K44: _.K45: _.K46: _.K47: _.K48: _.K49: _.K50: _.K51: _.K52: _.K53: _.K54: _.K55: _.K56: _.K57: _.K58: _.K59: _.K60: _.K61: _.K62: _.K63: _.K64: _.K65: _.K66: _.K67: _.K68: _.K69: _.K70: _.K71: _.K72: _.K73: _.K74: _.K75: _.K76: _.Klength: 77__proto__: Array[0]


leaflet.js:6 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
```

It looks like the decoding is not working properly. However, I can see that the encoded path is a real path (no typos or erros) by putting it into this interactive api and i get a nice route in a map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility?hl=en

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `google.maps.LatLng` is not the same as a `Leaflet.LatLng` (as ist seems you try to use the path in leaflet).

In a `google.maps.LatLng` `lat` and `lng` are **functions** (which return the particular floats)

In a `LeafLet.LatLng` `lat` and `lng` are **floats**

You must first convert the google.maps.LatLngs in the path to Leaflet.LatLngs  before you may use them in Leaflet.

Comment: thank you! that was the problem! Now it works:
var decoded_latlngs = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(latlngs);
var leaf_latlngs = []
for (var i = 0; i < decoded_latlngs.length; i++) {
  leaf_latlngs.push(L.latLng(decoded_latlngs[i].lat(), decoded_latlngs[i].lng()));
}
route = L.polyline(leaf_latlngs, {color: 'blue'})